# Replacing strings in a Connect 4 game in python after 4 in a row

Tags: python, oop

Here is my display board for a connect 4 game I made. **I am trying to replace the string if a player gets 4 in a row. Eg. Player 1 is 'o' so if theres 4 'o' it gets replaced with '-', to look like its crossed out.** I have already made a separate functions that check if player wins horizontally, vertically, diagonally, diagonally reversed in my `self.num_new_points(col, row, player)` function which returns the total 4-in-a-rows from all cases mentioned before (pls let me know if you need to see them although I think theres nothing to change in there). Thanks!

```
# 1 is player as 'o', 2 is AI as 'x', 0 is " "
# eg of self.items = [[1,1,1,0],[2,2,1,0],[1,2,1,1],[0,0,0,0]], [[col[row]]...]
# size = 4
def display(self):
        # Displays board
        print("_________________________________")
        print(f"Points player 1: {self.points[0]}               |")
        print(f"Points player AI: {self.points[1]}              |")
        print("_________________________________")
        for i in range(self.size):
            for x in self.items:
                x = x[::-1]
                if x[i] == 0:
                    print(" ", end=" ")
                elif x[i] == 1:
                    print("o", end=" ")
                    if self.num_new_points(column = self.items[x], row = self.items[x][i], player = 1) > 0:
                        "o".replace(1, "-")
                elif x[i] == 2:
                    print("x", end = " ")
                    if self.num_new_points(column = self.items[x], row = self.items[x][i], player = 2) > 0:
                        "x".replace(2, "v")
            print(" "*5)
        print('_' * (2*self.size-1))
        print(' '.join(map(str, range(self.size))))
```

Output:

```
    o   
o o o o
o x x
o x o
_______
0 1 2 3   

#expected:
    o   
- - - -
o x x
o x o
_______
0 1 2 3
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: Code `"o".replace(1, "-")` is totally useless - it change char in current string `"o"` but it can't change it on screen. You should use use variable `char = "o"` and inside `if` use `char = "-"` and later use `print(char, end=" ")`

Answer (score 0):

Code `"o".replace(1, "-")` is totally useless - it changes char in current string `"o"` but it can't change text on screen.

You should use use variable for this and later `print()`

```
char = "o"
if self.num_new_points(column = self.items[x], row = self.items[x][i], player = 1) > 0:
      char = "-"
print(char, end=" ")
```

But I don't know if it will work correctly.

Maybe you should first change values in `self.item` and later display it.

Comment: What do you mean by change values in self.item?

Comment: I means - maybe in self.item you should use `3` for `-`, and `4` for `|` and later display values. It is simpler to change values in list than when you display char by char. In list you can change previous chars, when you display then you can't change previous chars.